# add dropshadow effect to context menu in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, effect

I've tried to do this with CSS like this (test example):

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(one-pass-box, black, 10, 1.0, 3, 3)
}
```

but it doesn't work. Tried to find out which node i should style through ScenicView, but context menu disappearing before i can read info in SV. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, I currently have the same issue here. I found this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127999/how-do-you-set-the-style-for-a-javafx-contextmenu-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourMenu.setEffect(addLabelEffect());
```

Define the drop shadow in the classand check if its working. Here is a simple sample

```
private DropShadow addLabelEffect() {

        DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
        ds.setSpread(0);
        ds.setOffsetY(1.0);
        ds.setOffsetX(1.0);
        ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        return ds;

    }
```