# How to change MenuItem focus/hover color

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to change the highlight/focus/hover color of menu items.

[image]

I'm trying to change the blue background to another color, but nothing seems to work?

I've tried a few things with no luck from: [How do you set the style for a JavaFX ContextMenu using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127999/how-do-you-set-the-style-for-a-javafx-contextmenu-using-css)  and  [How to style menu button and menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299162/how-to-style-menu-button-and-menu-items)

```
.context-menu:focused {
    -fx-background-color:white;
    -fx-focus-color:white;
}

.menu-item:focused {
    -fx-background-color:white;
    -fx-focus-color:white;
}

.menu:focused {
    -fx-background-color:white;
    -fx-focus-color:white;
}
```

and many other variations...

Also some example code that's using the menu item's

```
// Menu
final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
```

and construct a MenuItem:

```
maximizeMenuItem = new MenuItem(Config.getString("Maximize"));
maximizeMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { /* do stuff */ }
```

I could try a:

```
contextMenu.setStyle("-fx-focus-color:white");
```

or

```
maximizeMenuItem.setStyle("-fx-focus-color:white");
```

but I can't seem to figure out which `-fx-` css tag controls that blue background color...

If possible, please post the `FXML` solution as well as the in-line code solution.

Comment: Better if you post the code in fiddle.

Comment: Did you try to change all `-fx-background-color: #006699;` to another color?

Comment: yes, if I do `contextMenu.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");`, it does make the background white, but when you hover over one of the menu items, it is still blue. So i guess i'm missing which fx css tag I need to use?

Comment: Is there a `.menu-item:hover` property...I seem to recall reading something?

Comment: Try taking a look at the menu-item styling in the default JavaFx stylesheet. Whatever is making the item blue is bound to be in there somewhere. [link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, a little embarrassed. I had my layers messed up to where my stylesheet wasn't being applied like I thought it was.

So the correct way to change the `menu-item`'s background color when focused is:

```
.menu-item:focused {
     -fx-background-color: #969A9F;
}
```

Once I found and sorted out my css layering problem, it now works as expected as result it:

[image]